# Issue with hover and display

Tags: html, css

i have a navbar with a horizontal submenu and issued with the submenu appearing on hover. I used display none to hide it but the hover code didn't work. Here is the whole code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 200px 0 0 14px; /* top, right, bottom, left*/
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
}

.nav a {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}

/*SUBNAV*/ 

.subnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

.subnav li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.nav li:hover .subnav ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Arda\Desktop\website 2\style1.css">
 <title>Sunucu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="ana"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="magaza"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Yetki</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kredi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So as you can see when you hover shop, it's supposed to show the submenu but it doesn't.

Comment: `.nav li:hover .subnav ul` is not a correct selector for your markup. the `.subnav` is NOT a child of your `.nav li`

Comment: How exactly do you want it to function? A sample diagram or illustration might help.

Comment: @showdev If you remove display none from the .subnav ul you can see that there is a full width submenu assigned for shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have structured your HTML wrong. You need to move your subnav div under the parent li.

Here is JQUERY for you. Updated your example. Gave fadeIn effect.

If you only want to use css check for the comment in css section.

```js
$( "li.has-subnav" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('.subnav').fadeIn(200);
  },
  function() {
    $('.subnav').fadeOut(200);
  }
);
```

```css
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 14px; /* top, right, bottom, left*/
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav a {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}

/*SUBNAV*/ 

.subnav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/** Uncomment the following css and remove jQuery to use only css **/

// .has-subnav:hover .subnav {
//   display: block;
// }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Arda\Desktop\website 2\style1.css">
 <title>Sunucu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="ana"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="magaza has-subnav">
              <a href="#">Shop</a>
              <div class="subnav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Yetki</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kredi</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you edited the code but the first was kind of what i was looking for. I've realized that my html structure was wrong.

Comment: I just updated one more time. Take a look. If that helps.

Comment: Also added comment in css, so if you want to use only css you can do that as well.

Comment: Yes, thanks for adding both css and jquery! and one last thing: how can i make the submenu full width?

Comment: Check now. I changed css little bit. Thing is when you make wrapper element position relative, you can make child element absolute and set child position where ever you want inside the wrapper with top, left, bottom, right css property. You get the idea you need to implement this how you want in your code.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much for helping me. I am barely new to web development so all the different properties in css confuses me a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS selects `.subnav` as a child of `.nav li`, but your HTML is not structured that way.
To use your current CSS, you'll need to move the `.subnav` into `.nav li`.
Example below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 14px;
  /* top, right, bottom, left*/
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
}

.nav a {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}


/*SUBNAV*/

.subnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

.subnav li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.nav li:hover .subnav ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="ana">
      <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="magaza">
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
      <div class="subnav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Yetki</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kredi</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

It seems that you want the dropdown menu to be horizontal, the full width of the page, and below the main navigation.

I set the subnav to be `position:absolute`. That way it can be positioned outside of its container `li.magaza` but still be triggered by a hover event on its ancestor.

I also added an opacity/visibility [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to fade the submenu in and out (without using JavaScript).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 14px;
  /* top, right, bottom, left*/
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
}

.nav a {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}


/*SUBNAV*/

.subnav ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility 0s .2s;
}

.subnav li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.nav li:hover .subnav ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="ana">
      <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="magaza">
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
      <div class="subnav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Yetki</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kredi</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>Page content goes here</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but now "shop" extends and the background of the subnav gets weird how do i fix that. By the way i've already tried your solution before and encountered with a similar problem. I didn't know what to do so i tried this method and it gave me the display problem...

Comment: You may want to specify how you want it to function in your question itself.

Comment: @Arda you are probably wanting to `absolute` position it then.

Comment: @Arda The `.subnav`. Something like this - `.subnav { position: absolute;  top: 100%;  left: 0; z-index: 9;}`. then remove the `overflow: hidden;` from your parent `ul` and set your `.nav li` to `position: relative;` to use it as an anchor point.

Comment: @zgood yeah but i dont want it to be a vertical dropdown menu.